# How to pass EC point format list using SSL_CTX?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, tls1.2, elliptic-curve

I need to pass the selected EC point format list to server or want to restrict server to use selected EC point . What is the OpenSSL API to achieve the same while generating the SSL_CTX. i can see that openssl 1.0.2* version has this support but i am not able to find  openssl API to do the same.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Mind your language first, if you don't understand the question then ask it again... check the response of @
Matt Caswell he has explained it clearly what was i meant...

Answer (score 4):

There is no API for doing this. There is only an API for getting the negotiated EC point formats from the SSL object:

```
SSL_get0_ec_point_formats()
```

You cannot restrict EC point formats that the server negotiates via an API. Although, weirdly, you are correct in that the SSL_CTX object does appear to have support for it - but that never seems to have been exposed via an API.

In 1.0.2 you could still achieve what you want by directly manipulating the SSL_CTX `tlsext_ecpointformatlist` and `tlsext_ecpointformatlist_length` fields directly. I would strongly recommend against doing this though as that capability is removed in OpenSSL 1.1.0 because these structures are opaque in that version.

Really though I would question why you want to do this at all??

Comment: Thanks for your response. actually i just wanted to know about the way to restrict the server to just support uncompressed ECpoint or being a client to just expose uncompressed point as part of ecpoint extension in client hello

Comment: Right. Like I said in my answer, this cannot be done directly via an API. You would have to reach inside the SSL/SSL_CTX objects to do so. If this is a requirement then I suggest you raise an issue on the OpenSSL github site: https://github.com/openssl/openssl